Is there any example a non self-injective , semi-perfect ring withthe projective cover of every simple module is also injective?
Is there any example a non self-injective, semi-perfect ring $R$ such that the projective cover of every simple module is also injective? In the article "When projective covers and injective hulls are isomorphic" by Boyle, she established some conditions equivalent to having an isomorphism between the the injective hull and projective cover of finitely generate module. According to this article such rings are the uniserial rings, but by that she means a ring $R$ in which each principal indecomposable right, and left ideal has a unique composition series as an $R$-module and where $R$ is a direct product of finitely many primary rings. In the same article, it is mentioned that this rings were characterized by Faith as right artinian rings in which the injective hull of cyclic right modules are cyclic. Yes so many conditions.
So maybe I'm looking for a non self-injective ring that is also "uniserial" in the sense explained before?
I only know that the type of ring I'm looking for should definetely not be local, otherwise  we would have that being $R$ semi-perfect, $R$ with  the canonical homomorphism $\pi: R \to R/m$ where $m$ is the only maximal ideal in $R$ would be the projective cover of $R/m$, and since we want that projective cover of every simple $R$ module ($R/m$ simple, and therefore  cyclic, and therefore finitely generated) is also injective, then $R$ would be self-injective. So maybe considering semi-local rings?

I think there's a typo in the title and first line, as I don't know what you mean by a non self-injective module. But if you mean what I think, every ring $R$ is the projective cover of $R$ itself, which is finitely generated, so if the projective cover of every finitely generated module is injective, then $R$ must be self-injective.

@JeremyRickard Thank you so much! Yes you are right about in  this case how I stated things $R$ will be always injective as a module, however what if we change fintelly generated to simple modules? Could we have a ring which is not self-injective ($R$ as a module is not injective) and every time we can compute the projective cover of a simple module , the projective cover will also be injective?

Let $R$ be a semiperfect ring such that the projective cover of every simple right module is injective. Then $R$ must be right self-injective.
For any ring $R$, the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ is a superfluous right ideal, so $R$ is the projective cover of $R/J(R)$.
Since $R$ is semiperfect, $R/J(R)$ is semisimple. Suppose $R/J(R)\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^nS_i$, where the $S_i$ are simple modules. Taking projective covers,
$$R\cong P(R/J(R))\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^nP(S_i)$$
is a finite direct sum of injective modules, and so is injective.

@Jeremy_Rickard Thank you so much!
